# How to check if array contains value, which is a property of an an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
    obj: {
          "abc": "xxxxx",
          "def": "yyyyy",
          "ghi": "zzzzz"
         }
```

and an array like this (only 1 value):

```
    array: ["def"]
```

result should be:

```
    array: ["yyyyy"]
```

Im not sure what to try, thats why i didn't.
I hope you can help me with that

Comment: `console.log([obj[array.toString()]]);`

Comment: @MohammadUsman just `obj[array]` will also work since it will be converted to string internally

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem to fit the body of the question.

Comment: Yeah, that might be. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map method to do it...

Code is:

```
obj = {
   "abc": "xxxxx",
   "def": "yyyyy",
   "ghi": "zzzzz"
}

array = ["def", "abc"];

array = array.map(elem => {
    if(obj[elem]){
        return obj[elem];
    }
})
```

now array will be ["yyyyy", "xxxxx"]

Answer (score 1):

If the array really only has one entry, you can easily use that entry get the value of the property it names using [brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
value = obj[array[0]];
```

To build a new array with just that value, you can use an array literal:

```
[value]
```

So all together:

```
array = [obj[array[0]]];
```

Live example:

```js
const obj = {
  "abc": "xxxxx",
  "def": "yyyyy",
  "ghi": "zzzzz"
};

let array = ["def"];

array = [obj[array[0]]];

console.log(array);
```